# I would like to update the results of a table that is returned via a SELECT statement

Tags: postgresql

I need to update the table (tb_order_line) and column (total_vat_sum) based on a calculation with 2 values from the same table (quantity and unit_price) and a 3rd one (c.vat) from another table.
Here'es the query I tried with a SELECT statement and the problem is it updates all rows with the same total amount of the calculation and not with the calculation for each row as it should.
Thanks for your help!

```
`UPDATE ventas.tb_order_line
    SET total_vat_sum =
        (SELECT SUM(ol.quantity * ol.unit_price * (1+c.vat))
        FROM ventas.tb_order_line AS ol  
        JOIN ventas.tb_product AS p
        ON ol.product_code = p.product_code
        JOIN ventas.tb_subcategory AS s
        ON p.subcategory_code = s.subcategory_code
        JOIN ventas.tb_category AS c
        ON c.category_code = s.category_code
);`
```

tb_product

[image: tb_product]

tb_order_line

[image: tb_order_line]

Comment: I don't understand the use of the aggregate function. You are tring to to update total_vat_sum as the sum for **all** order lines regardless of the order or product. That doesn't make sense to me. I think it would be better if you provided some sample data and the expected result. Do you want to just update a single order_line row with the result of `ol.quantity * ol.unit_price * (1+c.vat)` for **that** order line?

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
UPDATE ventas.tb_order_line
    SET total_vat_sum = quantity * unit_price * (1 + c.vat)
        FROM ventas.tb_product AS p
        JOIN ventas.tb_subcategory AS s
        ON p.subcategory_code = s.subcategory_code
        JOIN ventas.tb_category AS c
        ON c.category_code = si.category_code
        WHERE
            p.product_code = tb_order_line.product_code
);
```

`SUM` is an aggregate function so you will get one value for all the rows.

Comment: It still doen't work. I still get the same value in all rows but now it is not the grand total of all rows as before, but the corresponding to one of the rows while most rows should have  different values according to quantities and prices. Join problem?

Comment: Corrected I believe. Otherwise you will need to show the table schema for `tb_order_line` and `tb_product`.

Answer (score 0):

`FROM ventas.tb_order_line AS ol` selects every row from that table, for *each* of the updated rows. Instead, you need to do your join against the updated rows:

```
UPDATE ventas.tb_order_line ol
--                          ^^
SET total_vat_sum = (
    SELECT SUM(ol.quantity * ol.unit_price * (1+c.vat))
    FROM ventas.tb_category AS c
    JOIN ventas.tb_subcategory AS s ON  ON c.category_code = s.category_code
    JOIN ventas.tb_product AS p ON s.subcategory_code = p.subcategory_code
    WHERE p.product_code = ol.product_code
);
```